# Юнит-тестирование aiomysql

Tags: python, mysql, юнит-тесты, async-await, aiomysql

Для основы написания теста взял [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47160503/20137863) по  связанному вопросу на Stack Overflow, там описан код для тестирования синхронного `PyMySQL` (на котором базируется `aiomysql`). Приём с `AwaitableMock` взял с [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70969778/20137863).

Вот что получилось:

```py
class TestMySQL(unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    class AwaitableMock(unittest.mock.AsyncMock):
        def __await__(self) -> t.Iterator[t.Any]:
            self.await_count += 1
            return iter([])

    @unittest.mock.patch("<...>.aiomysql")
    async def test_x(self, mock_db):
        connection = self.AwaitableMock()
        mock_db.connect.return_value = connection

        cursor = unittest.mock.MagicMock()
        result = unittest.mock.MagicMock()

        cursor.__aenter__.return_value = result
        cursor.__aexit___ = unittest.mock.MagicMock()

        connection.cursor.return_value = cursor
```

У меня есть класс-враппер, в котором хранится результат `aiomysql.connect(<...>)` и через такую конструкцию выполняются SQL-запросы в методах:

```py
# self.connection = await aiomysql.connect(<...>)
async with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
    await cursor.execute(<...>)
```

Инициализация класса-враппера (`obj = await MySQLWrapper.async_init(<...>)`):

```py
class MySQLWrapper:
    @staticmethod
    async def async_init(host, port, user, password, db):
        connection = await aiomysql.connect(
            host=host,
            port=port,
            user=user,
            password=password,
            db=db
        )

            return MySQLWrapper(connection)

    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.connection = connection
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\u\Desktop\...\test\test_mysql_wrapper.py", line 50, in test_select
    await self.db.select("member", "id", 12345)
  File "C:\Users\u\Desktop\...\mysql_wrapper.py", line 51, in wrapper
    return await function(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\u\Desktop\...\mysql_wrapper.py", line 94, in select
    async with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

Не могу понять почему `self.connection` принимает None (`assert_called_with` который проверяет, что `aiomysql.connect()` запускался с нужными аргументами, отрабатывает без ошибок).

Comment: Нужно смотреть где вы значение в self.connection прописываете. Строка `# self.connection = await aiomysql.connect(<...>)` действительно закомментирована, или вы показываете, что этот код где-то выше выполняется?

Comment: Этот код выполняется выше, а конкретно в асинхронном статическом методе который возвращает объект класса-обёртки (пришлось так сделать, т.к. в обычном init нельзя нормально вызвать корутину).

Comment: Без более полного кода трудно что-то сказать. Возможно метод с инициализацией по какой-то причине не выполняется или выполняется позже.

Comment: Выполняется. Ошибка происходит именно при вызове методов с этим контекстным менеджером.

Comment: В любом случае нужно больше кода.

Comment: Дополнил кодом с "инициализацией" класса.